# crystal report columns issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

i need the detail section of the report to be divided into columns and set the number of rows

EX:

```
Revision Status     
IFC - Issued for Construction   CAN - Cancelled 
IFD - Issued for Design         C1 - Accepted   
IFI - Issued for Information    C2 - Accepted as Noted - Revise and Resubmit    
IFP - Issued for Purchase       C3 - Not Accepted - Revise and Resubmit 
IFR - Issued For Review         C4 - Review Not Required - Information Only 
IFU - Issued for Use            C5 - Accepted in MDR / IOM  
PLA - Placeholder               C6 - As Built
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a multi-column detail section is pretty easy - just go to Section expert, click `Format with Multiple Columns` and adjust settings on the `Layout` tab that shows up.

Now, to get an exact number of rows in those columns, I think you will need to mess with the margins or something. Or maybe you'll need to add a "Group By" based on a formula - I guess I'm still not 100% sure what you meant by that.